Is it possible to block temporarily the Windows Key and Control Esc using Python?
I am building a small app that will lock the computer after some time. It will create a full screen with a box to input password to unlock. So I am not actually using the normal windows lock
This app is to control the time my kids are playing on the computer.
I tried many ways including Keyboard library but nothing seems to work.
I looked in multiple places but nothing seems to work and my search on GPTs also is not delivering anything.
Is there a way to do it?
import keyboard

def block_windows_key(e):
    if e.name == 'windows' or e.name == 'ctrl+esc':
        return False  # Returning False blocks the key event
    else:
        return True   # Returning True allows the key event to be processed

keyboard.hook(block_windows_key)

# Keep the script running
keyboard.wait('esc')

